# Enable CrudRepository in Spring java config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data

I'm trying to implement Spring's repositories in my DAL. I'm following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) guide.

At the third step of "1.2 Query methods" paragraph we need to activate the repository package scanning with the following XML configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

</beans>
```

In my project I'm using only java config so this declaration is a little problematic for me. What is the right way to make things done in java conf in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following annotation to your configuration class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories")
```